# .htaccess redirect from url.co.za/file/file /directory/subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Im trying to redirect a url to a folder outside of the root folder exp.

www.url.co.za/newFolder/folder2
the folder structure is as follows

- root folder
- site folder
- newFolder/folder2

currectly if you navicate to url.co.za htaccess moves you to the site folder.
Now I want if users navicate to www.url.co.za/newFolder/folder2 the htaccess must reditect them to "/newFolder/folder2" witch is located outside of "site folder" any sucgestions

I'v tryed this

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?url.co.za/newFolder/folder2$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^$ /newFolder/folder2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

but it didn't work

Comment: `%{HTTP_HOST}` obviously does _not_ contain the request path.

Comment: Besides it is unclear what you actually ask. The example you give uses the identical path for both, before and after the rewriting. So no rewriting takes place. So please try to explain better what it actually is you want to do. What _exactly_ is the incoming request, what _exactly_ should it get rewritten to.

Comment: Yes, this question is very unclear. What is "site folder"? This doesn't appear to be apparent anywhere in the code. By the way, your current code, though invalid, *implies* that you are trying to redirect `http://www.url.co.za/newFolder/folder2` to **exactly the same location**. This is what is making your question unclear. (Side note: I suggest you review the [relevant documentation on mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to understand how it works.)

Comment: Or is `www.url.co.za` an actual folder, not the domain?